# Scroll bar jumping on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/gutWm/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" value="Search" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    background: gray;
    overflow: none;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

div:hover {
    overflow: auto;
}

ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Question:** If you scroll the div to bottom and move the mouse out of the div, the whole inner content (red border) will jump instead of stay still. **Why is that and how to fix?**

It doesn't make sense to me because there is no horizontal bar and there is nothing (ul) expanding outside the div width.

Comment: Please add your browser and screen resolution, I couldn't reproduce

Comment: Your trying to cause the scrollbar to be invisible, unless your mouse is over the `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS overflow doesn't have a `none` value. Use `hidden` if you want to hide the scrollbar when you mouse out of the div.

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    background: gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If not, then `overflow: auto;` will keep the scrollbar present.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the `overflow:auto` out of the `div:hover` and instead put it into the `div` part in css then it will fix it. Right now all you have is that you always put overflow only on hover instead of having it there full time.

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    background: gray;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```